# MP4 video not working in HTML page by using html 5 Video tag

Tags: html, video, html5-video, mp4

I have to add .mp4 (60 MB) file in one of my html page & using below line of code but its not working/displaying.

Only play button with "0.00" displaying on the html page.

MP4 File is placed in  website "assets/video" folder.

```
<video controls="controls" width="640" height="360">
<source src="../assets/video/RegiserUsingEmailAndPassword.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
                                    Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

But same line of code is working if i give a externel mp4 video path

```
<video controls="controls" poster="http://sandbox.thewikies.com/vfe-generator/images/big-buck-bunny_poster.jpg" width="640" height="360">
                                <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
                            </video>
```

Comment: can you show the <source> tag fully ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<html> 
<body> 

<video width="400" controls>
 <source src="New/video/aa.mp4.mp4" type="video/mp4">

</video>
```

try this. when i tried with this New/video/aa.mp4 my video didnt shown over the browser. then i tried by adding one more .mp4 after path then it worked.. try it. give one more mp4 after the video.mp4.

good luck..

Comment: give me your path where your video is located?

Comment: Its working after deploying the html page into a website that is hosted in IIS.
Might IIS have added supportive MIME type.